# to_json :include :order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to order included models?

format.json { render :json => @client.to_json(:include => { :videos => { :order => 'sortorder' } }) }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need made when you create your @client. In your SQL request

Comment: i don't understand this answer. Can you please try to elaborate?